Fast search of specific positions in a uint8_t vector using SIMD instructions
I have a vector V of uint8_t symbols and I need to partition it into a sequence of non-overlapping phrases. The partition algorithm is simple: a position V[i] is a break if V[i-1]>V[i] and V[i]<V[j], j>i being the smallest position with V[i]!=V[j]. The phrases are defined as each substring V[i..i'-1] that spans two consecutive breaks i and i'. For example, given the input V=ataagattggc, we obtain the partition V = at aag attggc. Notice V[i=9]=g is not a break because V[j=11]=c is smaller. In contrast, V[i=3]=a is a break because V[i-1=2]>V[3]<V[j=5].
It is possible to partition V in one scan in a simple way. However, I run this algorithm over inputs with hundreds of GBs, so the implementation would benefit from some vectorization. I am not an expert on SIMD instructions, but I think they can help to find the breaks.
I know how to compute if V[i-1]<V[i] using SIMD instructions, but efficiently finding V[j] is a bit more complex because it is not necessarily adjacent to V[i]. My first attempt was to use SIMD instructions to produce the sequence V' of equal-symbol runs (atagatgc in the example), compare adjacent positions, and map back the breaks to V. However, my NEON-based implementation seems to perform similarly to the scalar version.
Below, I wrote a rough idea of my implementation (I omitted some details to keep it simple). It might also be faulty as I haven't tested it exhaustively. I think the bottleneck is in the last two loops, as they can not be unrolled.
I think the key is to compare V[i] to V[j] directly using SIMD instructions, thus bypassing the construction of V'. However, I don't know how to achieve this.
Any ideas on how this can be improved?
size_t vec_par_neon(const uint8_t *text, off_t txt_size){

    off_t n_chuks = txt_size/16;

    for(off_t c=0, i=1;c<n_chunks;c++,i+=16){

        //check if text[i>=1] (i.e., V) differs from text[i-1]
        chunk_prev = vld1q_u8(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&text[i - 1]));
        chunk_curr = vld1q_u8(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&text[i]));
        uint8x16_t cmp_result = vceqq_u8(chunk_prev, chunk_curr);
        vst1q_u8(eq_res, cmp_result);


        //gather every pair (i,text[i]) such that text[i-1]!=text[i]
        int u=1;
        for(auto j=0;j<16;j++){
            diff_pos[u] = j;
            diff_sym[u] = text[i+j];
            u+=eq_res[j]==0;
        }

        if(u>1){
            //diff_sym=V' stores the equal-symbol runs 
            chunk_prev = vld1q_u8(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&diff_sym[0]));
            chunk_curr = vld1q_u8(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&diff_sym[1]));
            chunk_next = vld1q_u8(reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&diff_sym[2]));

            //compute every break V'[i>1] with V'[i-1]>V'[i]<V'[i+1]
            cmp_l_res = vcgtq_u8(chunk_curr, chunk_prev);
            cmp_r_res = vcgtq_u8(chunk_curr, chunk_next);
            uint8x16_t lm = vorrq_u8(cmp_l_res, cmp_r_res);
            vst1q_u8(&lm_res[1], lm);

            int o=0;//number of breaks in V'
            for(auto j=1;j<u;j++){
                lm_res[o] = j;
                o+=lm_res[j]==0;//move to the next break
            }

            //map the breaks from V' to V        
            for(auto j=0;j<o;j++){
                //the break is i+diff_pos[lm_res[j]]
            }
            
            diff_sym[0] = diff_sym[u-1];//set data for the next chunk
        }
    }
}


If your input is hundreds of GB, you are very likely bound by memory throughput (unless you managed to stream input and output in a way to keep everything in cache).

Why don't all of you people in computational genetics convert from strings to just use binary.  Ie, a=00, g=01, t=10, c=11.  The files are typically ASCII characters.  You would achieve a x4 speedup and reduce the file size by x4.  At least chunk stuff as codon in a byte, wasting two bits for overhead (like coding/non-coding).

@chtz Hardware might be able to DMA the data as they are processing other buffers.  I agree that fetch from RAM and the writing will bound performance.  However, it is best to do this in RAM burst and/or cache lines.  You can also use multiple cores to process different sections in parallel.

Improvements:
-- instead of loading chunk_prev every time, just save chunk_prev = chunk_next at the end of the loop.   At the moment you're loading two 128-bit vectors every iteration so you're ending up memory bound here.
-- not sure why the store to eq_res, it seems like this is a local array to conveniently access the elements as array elements.  You shouldn't do this and if needed use vget_lane to get elements of the vector.  But we can avoid it entirely.
-- gathering the number and locations of u, you can use vshrn_n_u16 with 4 shift positions to compress the bits into a form that gives you both the position and locations (See https://community.arm.com/arm-community-blogs/b/infrastructure-solutions-blog/posts/porting-x86-vector-bitmask-optimizations-to-arm-neon )
The check u > 1 will then become val != 0. The number of hits you can get with popcount, once you do those first two changes you should be able to see how to change the rest.
